# Droppable area not accepting drag element - jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z3uUF/3/ 
I'm trying to drop element with the image to dropbox(to droppable area) .It works fine within the jfiddle...
But if i copy paste the same code n check in my local machine after dropping the element into droppable area it doesn't take the draggable element ,  i need to place the drag element next to dropbox only then it takes.
I'm not able to figure out solution ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Since it works in jsfiddle (and it did), it will be hard to diagnose for me.

My gut feeling is that it has something to do with the accept parameter on the droppable.  I would start by removing that.

Comment: I have run into a problem when the droppable area isn't a block or has a height of 1px or something.  I've tested this by giving the droppable a border and/or setting the hover class for the droppable and giving it a background color.

Comment: when i add this parameter margin-left:300px - #makeMeDraggable { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; margin-left:200px}​  it doesn't work properly

Comment: if i drop the element  300px from the dropbox the element is accepted else it is not

Comment: is the element that you are dropping already apart of the droppable? Has the html changed in your local environment?

Comment: hey natedavisolds thanks for response .. will try to figure out the exact issue.